# How to display the product ratings in product thumbnails on the homepage in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, rating

I am using the Electro theme for an e-commerce website with Woocommerce plugin in wordpress.

My ratings & reviews are working fine. but the thing I just want to display my product ratings in the product thumbnails on the home page. The theme doesn't have the default option for this.

Is any way to achieve this?

Screenshot:
[image]